# Process a scope variable according to element size

Tags: angularjs

### Edited

I need an array in `$scope.images` processed with a function according to element size.

test.html looks like this

```
<div image-gallery>
  <div ng-repeat='img in images'>
    <img ng-src='{{img.thumbnail}}' style='width: {{img.newwidth}}'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm just wondering how to create a simple image-gallery directive that would use its own width on a function like

> $scope.images = CreateThumbnails($scope.images, element.innerWidth())

CreateThumbnails calculates a new attribute `newwidth` to the images in `$scope.images`. Of course it would be nice if they were calculated whenever browser size changes but a simple on load calculation would be sufficient.

### More edit

Right, so I can at least modify `$scope.images` if I call it like

```
$scope.images = Images.get({}, function(images) {
  CreateThumbnails(images, 1000)
}
```

Sadly that's in the controller so still wondering how to access $scope.images in a directive so that i can use the element.

### Update

Phew, finally got at least something working. I'll just have

```
$scope.images = Images.get({}, function() {
  CreateThumbnails($scope.images, $scope.elementwidth)
)
```

And then in the directive that contains the images

```
app.directive("imageGallery", function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.elementwidth = element.innerWidth();
  };
});
```

So at least it creates thumbnails on load, i'll try and see how I can check when browser is resized.

Answer (score 0):

`ngRepeat` directive runs at 1000 priority, if you want to handle the data before giving to `ngRepeat` you need to set `priotity` property with a value higher than `1000`. But most of the time you would not need to do so. You can create a directive which would encapsulate the `ngRepeat` portion, or even better, (which also would suit your case), create a directive at the repeating element, in your case, it would be `img` element itself.

Comment: You're right i dont need to use templates, i just want an array of elements processed. Edited question for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Alright sweet i can listen to window events in directives so got it working:

```
app.directive("imageGallery", function($window) {
  return function(scope, element) {
    scope.elementwidth = element.innerWidth();
    angular.element($window).bind("resize", function() {
      scope.elementwidth = element.innerWidth();
    });
  };
});

app.controller("ImageTestCtrl", function($scope, Imgs) {
  $scope.images = Imgs.index({}, function() {
    $scope.thumbs();
  });
  $scope.$watch("elementwidth", function() {
    $scope.thumbs();
  });
  return $scope.thumbs = function() {
    CalculateThumbnails($scope.images, $scope.elementwidth);
  };
});
```

Some duplication still because i think i have to keep using the callback on resources.